# Validating date, time start and time end with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've tried many ways to validate the date and time with Javascript functions but none seem to work. I'd like to alert users when their date input is of a past date whereas the time start cannot be the same as time end and it cannot be later than time end. 
My HTML codes:

```
<p>
<label> Date:
 <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required />
</label>
</p>

<p>
<label> Time start:
 <input type="time" id="timeStart" name="timeStart" required />
</label>
</p>

<p>
<label> Time end:
 <input type="time" id="timeEnd" name="timeEnd" required />
</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `var months = ["January", "February", ... ]`?

Answer (score 0):

could be you should convert you value in a proper date

eg:

```
   var d = new Date("03/25/2015");
   var n = d.getMonth();
```

Answer (score 0):

> As you can only store strings in localstorage so when you tried to
>   parse the JSON to get d, it turned to be a string. So you need to
>   convert it into Date Object before doing any operations on it as
>   mentioned by *scaisEdge*

```
var date   =  new Date(d);
var monthname  = month[date.getMonth()];
```

Refer https://jsfiddle.net/Ltufu0aj/